# Node.js: multi-node No such module

Tags: node.js

running Linux ubuntu 3.0.0-15-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 17:23:00 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Node.js 0.6.9

multi-node 0.2.3

Running this code (sudo node server.js):

```
    var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
});

var nodes = require("multi-node").listen({
        port: 80,
        nodes: 4
}, http);
```

I get this error:

```
    node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: No such module
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_files/node_modules/multi-node/lib/multi-node.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_files/server.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:444:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
```

Not sure how to rememdy this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try cluster, its very easy to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue filed for this on the multi-node.js bug tracker. See
https://github.com/kriszyp/multi-node/issues/14

Update: It turns out that `process.binding('net')` [was removed](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.4-and-v0.6) between 0.4 and 0.6. This explains your error message. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a fix. As a workaround, perhaps you should use [Node's cluster module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html) (as suggested by one of the commenters on the bug).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an old npm? Deleting the one in usr/bin fixed this problem for me:

$ rm /usr/bin/npm